# What is the performance difference between using DataStore vs ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-room, android-contentprovider, android-jetpack-datastore

I have been storing login credentials using the new Android DataStore. Has been working well, but now I need to share it between multiple apps using ContentProvider.

The problem is, I don't want to have another layer of maintenance by always having to remember to update the ContentProvider with the credentials while also updating the DataStore.

So the idea is, to use only the ContentProvider. But I'm afraid of the performance impact of changing the flow from:

`App <--> DataStore`

to:

`App <--> ContentProvider <--> Room Database`

Does anyone know how bad this change is for performance? Also, for some reasons I'm using Room Database as the storage for the ContentProvider.

Comment: `So the idea is, to use only the ContentProvider.` That does not match: `App <--> ContentProvider <--> Room Database`.

Comment: @blackapps When I say to only use the ContentProvider, I mean as opposed to using both the ContentProvider and the DataStore as means of storing the credentials. You can read it as ContentProvider+Room if it makes more sense.

Comment: The subject of your post still does not make sense. You cannot compare them.

Comment: @blackapps How is it not possible to compare the performance difference between accessing a DataStore directly vs accessing Room by querying a ContentProvider?